# BigQuery "Max retries exceeded" when running dbt

Tags: google-bigquery, dbt

When running dbt we randomly have some models failing with the following error:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host=‘bigquery.googleapis.com’, port=443): 
Max retries exceeded with url: /bigquery/v2/projects/xxxx/jobs 
(Caused by NewConnectionError(‘<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f7fdce6dbb0>:
 Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution’))
```

I tried to search online but I could not find anything related to this error and dbt.
Can this be some issue internal of dbt, or the cause is related to something external? Is there a way to prevent this?

We are running dbt targeting BigQuery using a workflow scheduler (Argo) in a GKE cluster.

Thank you! :)

Comment: This strongly suggests to me that something is wrong with your DNS settings and/or your VPN that is not allowing BQ to receive requests from your GKE cluster. I would start there.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, the problem was the usage of preemptible nodes in GKE. We had those errors when the dbt run was executing during a restart of the `kube-dns`/`kube-proxy` service.

We "solved" the problem by applying a retry logic in Argo in case of failures.